# Securely deny direct access to nodes except when link on another node is clicked

Tags: nodes, navigation, users

I'm hoping there's a module for this.

Let's say I have two nodes. First one is supposed to be a "gateway" to the second one with protected content on it.  What I'm trying to do is make the protected node accessible *only* by clicking a link on the "gateway" node, and display an error message if they try to go any other way (direct link, browser history, etc.)

For example, in one method, we could set a session variable or database entry or something that has the following info:

- Current user's ID
- Page being accessed
- IP address
- Timestamp
- Expiration (to prevent access by going to direct browser history)
- Single use "key" to be checked by receiving page

Then, when the user clicks a link to protected content on the "gateway" page, it sets the above variables and passes the "key" to the protected page, which then looks up the other data based on that key and allows/denies access accordingly.

Is there a module that does this sort of thing or gets us close? If not, what would be the best way to write something that does this?

Comment: Do you prefer to err on the side of allowing access when first node was not, in fact, visited? Or on the side of not allowing access when first one was visited properly?

Comment: Neither scenario is desirable, however the lesser of the two evils is the second scenario.

Comment: I might be wrong, but this seems like a very niche requirement - I'd be surprised if there's an existing module to do this. Writing your own should be pretty straightforward though, once you've got your authentication/one-time-key logic written. After that it's just a matter of a `hook_node_view()` for the relevant nodes, and check the session vars (or however you've decided to implement it)

Comment: Every security system, every access control system suffers some amount of false positives or false negatives. Sometimes both. They are never desirable, but it is pretty much needed to determine which you can live with. Now, I don't believe there is a module for that. What you need to do, apparently, is to generate a security token on the link (possibly JS onclick), tie it with user's session, IP, browser ID and all that, make it short lived. And on access check if passed security token is valid, all data matched, and timeout was not yet reached. That would about do it.

Comment: Would it not be much simpler to simply set a session variable on page 1, and deny access if it is not set on page 2. Once page 2 is served the session variable is removed. Simple.

Comment: Session variables would be simpler, yes, but there would have to be some mechanism that would need to be checked against what that session variable value *should* be that the page is expecting...though I suppose the value could be derived from the other data passed in session and just check it against that and the existing user ID and node ID once the second page loads.

Comment: @Jayar the main point is that this can be as simple or as complicated as your spec requires. Define what 'authentication' method you want to use, decide on the format, entropy, etc, and from there you can pick whatever you feel would be the simplest solution to implement, whether that's a session var, query parameter, whatever. We can't help you write that part of it here as it's not Drupal related, but check out PHP's `hash_hmac()` for a quick and easy method